# Prolog: create new list structure of known list

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to take one list and create a new one with another structure.

---

**The first list I have is something like this:**

```
List 1 out of X:
[[4,2,5,1,1,7,4],
[1,0,2,1,5,4,4],
[2,8,0,2,2,6,2],
[8,9,2,0,1,6,2],
[6,2,0,3,0,2,2],
[3,6,6,3,0,2,9],
[6,2,1,4,3,3,9]]
```

**The code I have at the moment is this:**

```
oneMap(V,[_,_,V]).
listMap([],[]).
listMap([H|T],[H1|T1]):-
listMap(T,T1),oneMap(H,H1).
```

The problem here is that I get each line in the list inside my new list, but instead I want the value inside the line.

**Part of the output at the moment:**

```
[[_G21217,_G21220,[4,2,5,1,1,7,4]],[_G21202,_G21205,[1,0,2,1,5,4,4]],...
```

**Looking for something like this:**

```
[[_G21217,_G21220,4],[_G21202,_G21205,2],[_G21202,_G21205,5],...
```

Comment: You know that `[A|[B|[C|[_,_,V]]]]` is the same as `[A, B, C, _, _, V]`?

Comment: In my head it was a list inside a list inside a list, but i see now that I am only taking the first tail of each "header".

Comment: Maybe a more concrete example of what you want it to look like would help. You could use a smaller example matrix to illustrate (like a 3x3 instead of a 7x7).

Comment: `[[[_,_,4],[_,_2]],
[[_,_1],[_,_5]]]`
 something like this, where underscore is nothing at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The solution:

okay I have after some time found something that helped me with my double list problem:

```
oneMap(V,[_,_,V]). 

listMap1([],[]).
listMap2([],[]).

listMap1([H|T],[H1|T1]):-
listMap1(T,T1),listMap2(H,H1).

listMap2([H|T],[H1|T1]):-
listMap2(T,T1), oneMap(V,H1).
```

If someone have a smarter solution would I like to hear it.